# TableView skipping when exapnded section cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, rx-swift

I try to implement the collapse/expand system for table view sections. When the user tapped on the section header, then it will inserts cells into section when tapped one more time on the same section header then it will deleting cells from section making "collapse" effect.

The problem is when I try to expand more than 2 sections starting from the bottom. Tapping section which has at least one cell shift whole content without animation to lower section position.

I use auto-layout from code and RxDataSource.

Here is how I bind data source:

```
    let dataSourceForPurchasersList = RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource<AnimatableSectionModel<ExpandableSectionModel, CustomerCellModel>>(configureCell: { (dataSource, tableView, indexPath, cellModel) -> UITableViewCell in
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: GuestTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? GuestTableViewCell
        cell?.setupCell(model: cellModel)
        return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
    })

    viewModel.dataSourceBehaviorPurchasersList
        .bind(to: self.ordersTableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSourceForPurchasersList))
        .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Here is how I handle section expand:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    guard let viewModel = self.viewModel else { return nil }
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: CustomersSectionHeader.reuseIdentifier) as? CustomersSectionHeader

...


    guard let models = try? modelsBehavior.value() else { return nil }

    let dataSourceSectionModel = models[section]
    header?.configView(model: dataSourceSectionModel)

    header?.tapClosure = { [weak modelsBehavior, weak header] in
        dataSourceSectionModel.expanded = !dataSourceSectionModel.expanded
        header?.updateSelectorImageView()
        modelsBehavior?.onNext(models)
    }

    return header
}
```

[Presenting the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvcyc.gif)

@edit

Solution:

I observed that the shift of content is equal to the section header height by implementing `scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` function  and it depends on the table view internal logic. I set headerHeight and estimatedHeight of the section header to equal value then I used this code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let divValue: CGFloat
    if self.guestsTableView.delegate === scrollView.delegate {
        divValue = self.guestsTableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight
    } else {
        divValue = self.ordersTableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight
    }

    let diff = abs(self.scrollViewOffsetLastY - scrollView.contentOffset.y)
    let rest = diff.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: divValue)
    if rest == 0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset.y = self.scrollViewOffsetLastY
    }
    self.scrollViewOffsetLastY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```

Comment: where is your code? How you tried?

Comment: you use auto layouts agreed, but where's the code that has a problem?

Comment: Ok, I added more details and gif presenting the problem